# Interior of a set in a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space, $f \in X'$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$;
Prove that: $$\text{int}\{x \in X: f(x) \ge \alpha\}=\{x \in X:f(x)>\alpha \}$$
I noted the set in the left by $A$ and the set in the right by $B$; so, I have to prove that: $\text{int}(A)=B$.
I thought to prove it by double inclusion; let $x \in \text{int}(A)$; so, $x \in A$, so $f(x) \ge \alpha$. To prove that $x \in B$, I have to show that $f(x)\neq \alpha$. Suppose that $f(x)= \alpha$. I dont know how I must continue to obtain a contradiction..Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Note: The equality doesn't hold if $f = 0$ and $\alpha = 0$, in which case the set on the left hand side is $X$, and the set on the right is $\varnothing$. It holds if $f \neq 0$ or $\alpha \neq 0$, however. The case $f = 0,\, \alpha \neq 0$ is easy. If $f\neq 0$, what do you know about $f(U)$ when $U$ is an open ball in $X$?

Comment: It is easy to see, that $B\subseteq A$ and $A$ is open. Now it sufficient to show that $A\backslash B$ has an empty interior.

Comment: $f(U)$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Can you prove it?

Comment: I will think about..

Comment: Let $U$ an open ball in $X$; so $U=B(x,\delta)$, with $x \in X$, $\delta>0$;we have that $||f(x)-f(y)|| \le M||x-y|| \le M \delta$, for all $y \in U$; so $f(U) \in B(f(x), M\delta)$.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: I used the fact that if $f \in X'$, then $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The interior of a set $A$ is the set of all of its interior points. An interior point $x$ is a point such that $B_ε(x)\subset A$ for some $ε>0$. Take $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=α$. Can you show that $x$ is not an interior point? Or more precisely can you show that $B_ε(x)\subset A \iff f(x)>α$?